# error: unknown type name 'uint64_t' on MacOS while installing libraries

Tags: xcode, macos, pip, airflow, macos-catalina

Kept getting the following error when trying to install Apache Airflow by 
`pip install apache-airflow`
I removed command line tools, upgraded OS from Mojave to Catalina, re installed xcode using `xcode-select --install` even then the following errors failed to get resolved :-

```
---many similar lines---
    In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
    In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
    In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
    /usr/local/include/stdint.h:2:10: error: #include nested too deeply
    #include <stddef.h>
             ^
    /usr/local/include/stdint.h:72:11: error: #include nested too deeply
    # include <sys/types.h>
              ^
    /usr/local/include/stdint.h:82:11: error: #include nested too deeply
    # include <inttypes.h>
              ^
    In file included from src/setproctitle.c:14:
    In file included from src/spt.h:15:
    In file included from src/spt_python.h:14:

---many similar lines---
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:216:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
            uint64_t ri_wired_size;
            ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Read these issues on Github https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1388 and https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2009

Renamed my folder `/usr/local/include` to `/usr/local/include_old` for keeping it as backup in case even this doesn't work

`mv /usr/local/include /usr/local/include_old`
and then ran same installation command again:-

`pip install apache-airflow` 
which worked flawlessly this time.